# How o start code in Solana contract?

Tags: solidity, rust

Hello guys try to code in Solana contract, but didnt know how to start it. Will be happy to any advise how to start :)) Thank u :)

May be exist some video course in youtube or something like crypto zombie for solidity:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go though helloworld example on Solana

https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld/blob/master/src/program-rust/src/lib.rs

https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld/tree/master/src/program-c/src/helloworld